# Logarithm of an integral involving generalized real binomial coefficients

Tags: integration, special-functions, asymptotics, approximation-theory, gamma-function

I could not find a closed form for this integral although I think it should have been studied.

What is a good approximation to $I$ in

$$I=\ln\Bigg(\int_{0}^y\binom{2m}{m(1+x)}dx\Bigg)$$ where $0\leq y\leq1$ holds under reasonable definition of $\binom{n}{z}$ where $z\in\mathbb R$ and $0\leq z\leq n$?

The approximation I get for the integral itself is $\frac{2^{2m}}{m}\mathsf{erf}\Big(\frac{\sqrt{m}y}{\sqrt2}\Big)$ using standard binomial approximation and as one can see this does not tally well with $2^{2m}$ value that should be expected at $y=1$.

So is there a better approximation than what is provided by this for the logarithm of the integral?

Answer (score 1):

I presume you mean an approximation of
$$I(m,y)=\ln\Bigg(\int_{0}^y\binom{2m}{m(1+x)}dx\Bigg)$$
in the large-$m$ regime; the expansion of the binomial coefficient that you indicate then gives 
$$I_\infty(m)=2m\ln 2-\ln m$$
independent of $y\in(0,1]$. This is quite accurate, see the plot (the two lines are almost indistinguishable, blue is $I_\infty(m)$, gold is $I(m,y)$ for $y=1/2$).

[image]

The approximation remains good for quite small $y$, in particular one has $I_\infty(100)=134.02$, while $I(100,1)=133.33$, $I(100,0.1)=133.16$, $I(100,0.01)=131.14$.

Comment: What approximation you use for the binomial coefficient and what do you use when $x\in(0,1)$ and $m(1+x)\not\in\mathbb Z$?

Comment: What is the gamma function expression? You say you are using $\mathsf{erf}$ approximation?

Comment: $I_\infty$ is the large-$m$ limit of $\ln\left[\frac{2^{2m}}{m}\mathsf{erf}\Big(\frac{\sqrt{m}y}{\sqrt2}\Big)\right]$

Comment: Thank you.. what is the gamma function expression? Perhaps I miscalculated or misinterpreted. Lemme check.